# How to yield multiple objects with respect to a multi-valued column in Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, dynamic-linq

**Scenario:**
I have to export an excel file which will contain list of Parts. We have enabled the user to select the columns and get only selected columns' data in the exported file. Since this is a dynamic report, I am not using any concrete class to map the report as this will result in exporting empty column headers in the report, which is unnecessary. I am using Dynamic Linq to deal with this scenario.

I have a list of dynamic objects fetched from dynamic linq.

```
[
    {"CleanPartNo":"Test","Description":"test","AliasPartNo":["258","145","2313","12322"]},
    {"CleanPartNo":"Test1","Description":"test1","AliasPartNo":[]}
]
```

How can I get 4 rows out of this json like

[image]

Please note that I cannot use a strongly typed object to deserialize/ Map it using JSON.Net

*Update*
Following is the code:

```
 public class Part
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CleanPartNo { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<PartAlias> AliasPartNo { get; set; }
    }

public class PartAlias
    {
        public int PartId { get; set; }
        public int PartAliasId { get; set; }
        public string AliasPartNo { get; set; }
    }




var aliases = new List<PartAlias> {
                new PartAlias{AliasPartNo="258" },
                new PartAlias{AliasPartNo="145" },
                new PartAlias{AliasPartNo="2313" },
                new PartAlias{AliasPartNo="12322" }
            };
List<Part> results = new List<Part> {
                new Part{CleanPartNo="Test", Description= "test", PartAlias=aliases  },
                new Part{CleanPartNo="Test1", Description= "test1" }

            };

var filters = "CleanPartNo,Description, PartAlias.Select(AliasPartNo) as AliasPartNo";
var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results.AsQueryable().Select($"new ({filters})"));
```

in the dynamicObject variable I get the json mentioned above

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Specifically how do I set up this code to run it in a Console App?

Comment: I have updated the code, please check

Comment: can we know the names of the columns that are arrays? This would make this 2 liner

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: The following relies on anonymous classes, which is not exactly the same as dynamic LINQ (not at all), but I figured that it may help anyway, depending on your needs, hence I decided to post it.

To flatten your list, you could go with a nested `Select`, followed by a `SelectMany` (**Disclaimer:** This assumes that every part has at least one alias, see below for the full code)

```
var flattenedResult = result.Select(part => part.AliasPartNumber.Select(alias => new 
                                                                                 { 
                                                                                     CleanPartNo = part.CleanPartNo, 
                                                                                     Description = part.Description,
                                                                                     AliasPartNo = alias.AliasPartNo
                                                                                 })
                            .SelectMany(part => part);
```

You are first projecting your items from `result` (outer `Select`). The projection projects each item to an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type in which each item corresponds to an alias part number. Since the outer `Select` will yield an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>` (or omething alike), we are using `SelectMany` to get a single `IEnumerable` of all the items from your nested `IEnumerables`. You can now serialize this `IEnumerable` of instances of an anonymous class with `JsonConvert`

```
var json = sonConvert.SerializeObject(flatResults);
```

#### Handling parts without aliases

If there are no aliases, the inner select will yield an empty `IEnumerable`, hence we will have to introduce a special case

```
var selector = (Part part) => part.AliasPartNumber?.Any() == true
                                  ? part.AliasPartNumber.Select(alias => new 
                                                                         { 
                                                                             CleanPartNo = part.CleanPartNo, 
                                                                             Description = part.Description,
                                                                             AliasPartNo = alias.AliasPartNo
                                                                         })
                                  : new[]
                                    {
                                        new 
                                        { 
                                            CleanPartNo = part.CleanPartNo, 
                                            Description = part.Description,
                                            AliasPartNo = alias.AliasPartNo
                                        }
                                    };
var flattenedResult = result.Select(selector).SelectMany(item => item);
```

Comment: This answer somehow gave me some idea but its not what I actually want. I cannot use the concrete types.

Comment: @AliHasan Then maybe you could give some more context in the question. This may help to give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

From json you provided you can get values grouped by their name in this way:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
var lookup = array.SelectMany(x => x.Children<JProperty>()).ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

then this is just a manner of simple loop over the lookup to fill the excel columns.

However, I would suggest to do the flatenning before JSON. I tried for some time to make it happen even without knowing the names of the columns that are arrays, but I failed, and since it's your job, I won't try anymore :P

I think the best way here would be to implement custom converter that would just multiply objects for properties that are arrays. If you do it well, you would get infinite levels completely for free.